# Unable to build_image when using Docker provisioner on vagrant

Tags: vagrant, docker

When I try to use the Docker provisioning in Vagrant

```
config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
  d.build_image "/vagrant/app"
end
```

I get the error

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix the following errors and try again:
VagrantPlugins::Docker::Config:
  * The following settings shouldn't exist: build_image
```

when running `vagrant up`

I'm able to run the build manually inside a VBox VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build_image` configuration was introduced in Vagrant 1.5.0. Maybe you have an older version?

Comment: You were right, brew cask is very deceptive when updating